# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'some_props')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with React conditional rendering. I want to render a specific prop if it's set so first I'm checking if the prop exists and then outputing it otherwise output 0, but React has a problem checking if the variable exists when it's undefined at first load...

```
number:
    props.dashboardCards[0].items.thisMonth[0].itemTitle
      ? props.dashboardCards[0].items.thisMonth[0].itemTitle
      : 0,
```

This is my code I want to create an object with number field and in that field I want to set this prop if it exists otherwise 0.
And React keeps giving me error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'itemTitle')

Comment: The `thisMonth` array is probably empty ...

Comment: Yes obviously, I'm looking for a way to check if the array exists and if it does output array otherwise output 0...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`thisMonth` is probably empty or undefined. You can use optional chaining to solve this:

```js
number: props.dashboardCards[0]?.items?.thisMonth[0]?.itemTitle ?? 0,
```

Now if `props.dashboardCards[0].items.thisMonth[0].itemTitle` exists `number` will be the value of it, or it'll be 0.

The optional chaining operator (?.) enables you to read the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to check that each reference in the chain is valid.

Learn more about optional chaining from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Comment: Another thing you can do is use a variable to help generate a default value. `const { thisMonth = [] } = props....`

Answer (score 1):

The error says that there is no `itemTitle` in the `thisMonth` array.

If it's coming from the API, you need to wait to get it. You can simply check the `props` by the `console.log(props)` and check it before using dot notation to get the `itemTitle`.

You can also check for a value with optional chaining `?` :

```
props?.dashboardCards[0]?.items?.thisMonth[0]?.itemTitle
```

It means:

```
if(props){
  if(dashboardCards[0]){
    if(items){
      if(thisMonth[0]){
        props.dashboardCards[0].items.thisMonth[0].itemTitle
      }
    }
  }
}
```